# How to use Gitlab CI/CD to create release

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on optimizing my work pipeline using Gitlab CI/CD tools.

Here's how I define the release phase in the .yml file in my project.

```
release-job:
  stage: release
  tags:
    - keller
  needs:
    - job: deploy-job
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - echo "Create release"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG 
  release:
    tag_name: '$TAG'  
    description: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    name: 'Release $TAG'
    assets:
      links:
        - name: 'asset1'
          url: 'https://example.com/assets/1'
          filepath: 'build/release' # optional
          link_type: 'other' # optional
```

this "release-job" part is my attempt to do this after some references.

[Gitlab: How to generate release assets using Gitlab's CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77310247/gitlab-how-to-generate-release-assets-using-gitlabs-ci-cd)

[Gitlab offical page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_cicd_examples.html)

I didn't really get it and I get the following error message after push commit to remote server

> release-cli : The term 'release-cli' is not recognized as the name of
> a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
> is correct and try again.

I used my own gitlab-runner which is tag as "keller".
I want to collect the asserts ,which are stored in "build/release", after "deploy-job" and use them to create a release in Gitlab repository.

My working env is Windows, the asserts are some dll and exe files which are build by c++.

I would like to know how to write the release part in .yml file in order to reach my idea?

Comment: what type of runner is keller?

Comment: is windows powershell

Comment: install release-cli on it

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_cli.html#install-the-release-cli-for-the-shell-executor Found in https://docs.gitlab.com/search/?q=%22release-cli%22&page=1

Comment: I have installed the release-cli and added it into system env. Then I checked its version is 'release-cli version 0.16.0' . but the error message keeps the same...